# Why am I having "Invalid syntax in Python?"

Tags: python, syntax

In the following code sample, the last line (`print buildConnectionString(myParams)`) is throwing the following error:

> Invalid syntax

```
def buildConnectionString(params):

return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myParams = {"server":"mpilgrim", \
                "database":"master", \
                "uid":"sa", \
                "pwd":"secret"
               }
    print buildConnectionString(myParams)
```

Comment: Show us the full error message.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Also, no need for `\ ` when breaking lines within `{ }`, `( )` ... :)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you're on Python 3, print is a function and needs to be wrapped in parentheses:

```
print(buildConnectionString(myParams))
```

Comment: It's good to be grateful. Please also mark the answer as correct, so Randy get the well earned points... :-)